# What does "de no idou" mean (in relation to flights)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, words

In my Japanese text book it says the following:

```
Rondon kara jyuuichi jikan no hikouki de no idou desu /
it's 11 hours flight from London

hikouki de no idou = flight
```

I understand `hikouki` means `flight` and `idou` means `change`.
But I don't follow what `hikouki de no idou` means. Could someone explain? Thanks!

Comment: that's why you should not use textbooks with *only* romaji

Comment: I'm kind of surprised to see non-standard romanization like that in a textbook.  Did you romanize this yourself, big_smile?

Comment: @snailplane, No, it was like that in the book.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the wrong `idou`.  This 異動 means "change(s)".  This 移動 means "movement/transfer", or can be used for "travel".  Also, `hikouki` means "airplane".  I've never heard it used to mean "a flight"; that is usually [便]{びん}.

So it means `An 11-hour airplane travel/trip from London`.

Comment: Yes, unless the learners have not yet reached to the level where same pronunciation could happend in accorandce with Kanji, well, that would be hard for them, I think.